# Data Calculation for joining two tables

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I am studying Foxpro to create a simple application for manipulating data from two tables `A` and `B` (size of tableB `>>` size of tableA). The data from an `Excel spreadsheet` is imported into these two tables.

```
tableA
id            balance    load    state     
1             10         null    l
2             22         null    l 
3             31         null    l

tableB  
Load id     id      ord        fact   type   1st value  rounded value   state
    1        1        1        0.09      1      null        null         l
    2        1        2        0.02      0      null        null         l
    3        1        3        0.13      1      null        null         l
    4        1        4       -0.05      0      null        null         l
    5        2        1        0.01      1      null        null         l
    6        2        2        0.092     1      null        null         l
    7        2        3        0.03      0      null        null         l
    8        3        1        0.14      1      null        null         l
    9        3        2        0.12      0      null        null         l
   10        3        3       -0.02      0      null        null         l
```

My friend wants me to write a Foxpro code to do the following things: first, create empty tableA and tableB containing the columns shown above. Each columns will be loaded by (hundreds of thousands) of data  from an excel spreadsheet everyday. Second, **for each unique id**, the code updates the 3 columns `1st value`, `rounded value` and `load` with given formulas:

`1st value[i] = If(Type[i]=0, load[i-1]*fact[i], load[i-1]*fact[i]/(1-fact[i]))`

`1st value[1] = If(Type[1]=0, balance[1]*fact[1], balance[1]*fact[1]/(1-fact[1]))`

`rounded value[i] = If(1st value[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)`

`load[i+1] = load[i] + rounded value[i+1] (i >= 1)`

`load[1] = balance[1] + rounded value[1]`

I think I have to create a table like the following to store the calculation above for this step:

```
Calculation Table
  balance     id      ord    1st value  rounded value    load    
  10          1        1      0.989         0.90        10.9 (= 10 + 0.9)
  10.9        1        2      0.218         0.20        11.1 (= 10.9 + 0.2)
  11.1        1        3      1.658         1.60        12.7 (= 11.1 + 1.6)
  11.06       1        4     -0.635        -0.64        11.06 (=12.7 + (-0.64))
```

**Desired output**

Using results in `Calculation Table`, we update the original `tableA` and `tableB` as follows:

```
tableB    
Load id     id      ord       1st value  rounded value   state
    1        1        1        0.989          0.90       calculated        
    2        1        2        0.218          0.20       calculated     
    3        1        3        1.658          1.60       calculated 
    4        1        4       -0.635         -0.64      calculated 
    5        2        1        ...            ....      calculated 
    6        2        2        ...            ....      calculated 

tableA (Note: for each value in `load id`, the `load` column only stores the **last** value in the `calculation` table which corresponds to maximum `ord`)
id            balance    load    state     
1             10         9.5     calculated
2             22         ...     calculated 
3             31         ...     calculated
```

Can anyone please help me with the syntax for creating `tableB`, computing and store results for columns `1st value`, `rounded value` and `load` into a `calculation` table with `Inner Join` function on `id` column between tableA and tableB , and update `tableB`?

**My attempt:**

First step (Creating two tables A and B with column fields shown above)

```
CREATE TABLE tableA; 
(     id    int,    ;
      balance   double, ;
      load   C(240), ;
      state  C(240), ;)

CREATE TABLE tableB; 
(     Load id   int, ;
      id        int, ;
      ord       int, ;
      fact      double,  ;
      type      binary (not sure....)  ;
     1st value  C(240),;
      rounded value  C(240), ;
      state     C(240), ;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(adding as another answer just because others got too long to read)

> can you try your code with this dataset
>   (drive.google.com/open?id=1uCWwt5ubd2_F8w2gsh3v4VDpibWz7PAz) to see if
>   you will get the two output tables from your code, each similar to the
>   one shown in the previous Excel worksheet I uploaded for you?

I downloaded that spreadsheet and here is what I needed to change:
Your ranges were C8:F35 and H8:O62 for tableA and B. Also your "balance" was named "base". New code (downloaded to d:\temp\workbook2.xlsx) edited to match ranges and "balance" to "base":

```
* Get the data from given excel filename and ranges
* first range is tableA, second one is tableB
GetDataFromExcel("d:\temp\WorkBook2.xlsx", "Sheet1$C8:F35", "Sheet1$H8:O62")

* Now data is in cursors csrA and crsB do the calculation in these
DoCalculation()

* Done. Show the results selecting and browsing the crsA and B
Select crsA
Browse
Select crsB
Browse

* Get specific fields only from crsB
Select loadId, id, ord, firstVal, roundedVal, state ;
from crsB ;
into cursor crsBCustom ;
nofilter
browse

* Check data from both cursors (join)
* I chose the fields as I see fit
* ta and tb are local aliases for crsA and crsB
* helping to write shorter SQL in this case

Select tb.LoadId, tb.Id, ta.base, ta.load, ; 
       tb.firstValue, tb.roundVal, ;
       ta.State as StateA, tb.State as StateB ;    
from crsA ta ;
inner join crsB tb on ta.Id = tb.Id ;
order by tb.Id, tb.Ord ;
into cursor crsBoth ;
NoFilter
browse


* Does the specific calculations on specific data
Procedure DoCalculation
    *1st value[1] = If(Type[1]=0, Base[1]*fact[1], Base[1]*fact[1]/(1-fact[1]))

    *rounded value[i] = If(1st value[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)
    *rounded value[1] = If(1st value[1]>0, rounddown(1st value[1], 1), roundup(1st value[1],2)

    *load[1] = Base[1] + rounded value[1]

    * i > 1 - ord > 1
    *1st value[i] = If(Type[i]=0, load[i-1]*fact[i], load[i-1]*fact[i]/(1-fact[i]))

    *rounded value[i] = If(1st value[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)

    *load[i+1] = load[i] + rounded value[i+1] (i >= 1)

    *declare local variable
    Local lnBase

    * select crsB and create an index there
    Select CrsB
    Index On Padl(Id,10,'0')+Padl(ord,10,'0') Tag ALinkB

    * select crsA as parent and link to crsB 
    * using the "id" part of index
    Select crsA
    Set Relation To Padl(Id,10,'0') Into CrsB

    * start looping the rows
    Scan
        * working with a new Id (1, 2, ...)
        * save base value to m.lnBase
        lnBase = crsA.Base

        * select crsB and start looping the rows there
        * because of the index in effect and the relation created
        * pointer would be on the first crsB row with a matching Id 
        * and since Ord is also part of the index the first row of 
        * given Id
        * Limit the looping in crsB (child table) to Id in crsA
        * using WHILE clause 
        Select CrsB
        Scan While Id = crsA.Id
            * do replacing starting on first row of this Id (Ord=1)
            * we don't have any scope clauses in replace, thus 
            * we are doing "single row" updates

            Replace ;
                firstValue With m.lnBase*fact / Iif(!Type, 1, 1-fact),  ;
                roundVal With Iif(firstValue > 0, ;
                roundDown(firstValue,1), ;
                roundUp(firstValue, 2))
            * after each replace update m.lnBase value 
            * to use in next row   
            lnBase = m.lnBase + CrsB.roundVal
        Endscan
        * completed updating crsB
        * select crsA and also update crsA.base with final 'load' value
        Select crsA
        Replace Load With m.lnBase
    Endscan
    * Update state to 'Calculated'
    Update crsA set state = 'Calculated'
    Update crsB set state = 'Calculated'
Endproc

* Get data from excel with given filename and ranges
* This code is not generic and expects the 
* data to be in a specific format.
* Does not do any error check 
Procedure GetDataFromExcel(tcExcelFileName, tcTableARange, tcTableBRange)
    * declare and define the connection string to excel
    Local lcConStr
    lcConStr = ;
        'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;'+;
        'Data Source='+Fullpath(m.tcExcelFileName)+';'+;
        'Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"'

    * Declare and define the 2 SQL needed to get data for A and B
    * rename the fields in SQL for easier handling
    Local lcSQLA, lcSQLB
    TEXT to lcSQLA textmerge noshow
Select [id], [base], [load], [state]
from [<< m.tcTableARange >>]
    ENDTEXT

    TEXT to m.lcSQLB textmerge noshow
select
   [Load Id] as LoadId,
   [Id], [Ord], [Fact], [Type],
   [1st value] as firstValue,
   [Rounded value] as roundVal,
   [State]
from [<< m.tcTableBRange >>]
    ENDTEXT

    * Execute the queries and place results in given cursors 
    ADOQuery(m.lcConStr, m.lcSQLA, "crsTableA")
    ADOQuery(m.lcConStr, m.lcSQLB, "crsTableB")

    * Sanitize the cursors a bit
    * (OledB query would assign rather generic datatypes)
    Select Cast(Id As Int) As Id, Cast(Base As Double) As Base, ;
        Cast(Load As Double) As Load, Cast(State As c(50)) As State ;
        from crsTableA ;
        into Cursor crsA ;
        readwrite
    Select Cast(LoadId As Int) As LoadId, ;
        Cast(Id As Int) As Id, Cast(ord As Int) As ord, ;
        Cast(fact As Double) As fact, Cast(Type As logical) As Type, ;
        Cast(firstValue As Double) As firstValue, ;
        Cast(roundVal As Double) As roundVal, ;
        Cast(State As c(50)) As State From crsTableB ;
        into Cursor CrsB ;
        readwrite
    Use In (Select('crsTableA'))
    Use In (Select('crsTableB'))
Endproc

* roundUp and down custom functions

* RoundUp and Down excel style
* Not correct math wise IMHO
Procedure roundUp(tnValue, tnPlaces)
    Local lnResult, lnValue
    lnValue = Abs(m.tnValue)
    If Round(m.lnValue, m.tnPlaces) != m.lnValue
        lnValue = Round(m.lnValue+((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
    Endif
    Return Sign(m.tnValue) * m.lnValue
Endproc

Procedure roundDown(tnValue, tnPlaces)
    Local lnResult, lnValue
    lnValue = Abs(m.tnValue)
    If Round(m.lnValue, m.tnPlaces) != m.lnValue
        lnValue = Round(m.lnValue-((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
    Endif
    Return Sign(m.tnValue) * m.lnValue
Endproc


* Generic function to query a given data source
* and place results in a cursor  
Procedure ADOQuery(tcConStr,tcQuery,tcCursorName)
    Local oConn As 'ADODB.Connection'
    Local oRS As ADODB.RecordSet
    oConn = Createobject('ADODB.Connection')
    oConn.Mode= 1  && adModeRead
    oConn.Open( m.tcConStr )
    oRS = oConn.Execute(m.tcQuery)
    RS2Cursor(oRS,m.tcCursorName)
    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close
Endproc

* Helper function to ADOQuery to convert
* an ADODB.Recordset to a VFP cursor
Procedure RS2Cursor(toRS, tcCursorName) && simple single cursor - not intended for complex ones
    tcCursorName = Iif(Empty(m.tcCursorName),'ADORs',m.tcCursorName)
    Local xDOM As 'MSXML.DOMDocument'
    xDOM = Createobject('MSXML.DOMDocument')
    toRS.Save(xDOM, 1)
    Xmltocursor(xDOM.XML, m.tcCursorName)
Endproc
```

This is the whole code. Just changing the filepath and name to yours, select all the code, right click and execute selection to see results. Or save it as a prg, say ImportMyExcel.prg and run it:

```
ImportMyExcel()
```

You could see the results I have so I didn't upload any results.

> Also, is Procedure RS2Cursor(toRS, tcCursorName) intended to generate
>   the 2 output tables? Why do we need this procedure though: Procedure
>   ADOQuery(tcConStr,tcQuery,tcCursorName)?

Well those procedures are a little tricky for a newcomer (maybe not). I think you should know the history of VFP, cursors, cursor adapters, converting ADO recordset to a cursor etc (probably advanced level). I don't know, those were the procedures I came up with and published also on the foxite link that I gave to you. Just think they are black boxed (like a built-in one) functions doing they are work. ADOQuery's work is to simply query an OLEDB source and return the result as a cursor. With a cursorAdapter you might not need such a procedure but that procedure was designed before CursorAdapter existence.

> Two more questions please:  1) where does the m come from in 
>   m.lnBalance?

m. explicitly notifies the compiler that it is a **memory variable**. It is referred to as MDOT. There are developers who claim it is not needed and generally it leads to long running discussions (and likely you would find my name in those discussions). Up until today nobody could show and\or demonstrate me why we shouldn't or we don't need to use it. If you believe me it is not a preference but a thing that you should use.

> 2) Don't we need to define  crsTableA? Or you meant we can use the
>   CREATE Table tableA in your previous code to make crsTableA valid?

No. There is no table in that code. We read the data from excel into a cursor (crsTableA and crsTableB initially) and then sanitize into 2 cursors crsA and crsB. All of them are cursors. Cursors are like tables but are not persisted on disk. They may even spend all their life in memory and are gone when you close them. Here I preferred cursors because without harming any real data you could run N times and check your results. When you are satisfied persisting the data is as simple as a "Select ... into" or "insert into ..." (there are more ways too) a table. Even in the case of a table you don't need to use "Create Table ...". A "select Into ..." command can select the data from a source and save it to a table by creating it (like a combined 'create table ...' and then 'insert into ...').

> Also, I saw that B9:E12 does not match the range of tableA or tableB
>   in the Excel spreadsheet I uploaded for you before. Am I missing
>   something here?

It matched your original samples if you think data starts at B9 and G9 respectively.

> I have another question:  can you please clarify on what these lines
>   do: Select CrsB     Index On Padl(Id,10,'0')+Padl(ord,10,'0') Tag
>   ALinkB     Select crsA     Set Relation To Padl(Id,10,'0') Into CrsB.

I think I explained this part in the previous question. I will soon comment the code itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180838/discussion-between-user177196-and-cetin-basoz).

Answer (score 1):

Adding as another answer to prevent clutter. I can do further explanations if you need to. Here I used the Excel ranges that would match to sample data. You would replace the range with the actual one (as well as the excel filename):

```
GetDataFromExcel("c:\myFolder\myExcel.xlsx", "B9:E12", "G9:N19")
DoCalculation()
Select crsA
Browse
Select crsB
Browse

Procedure DoCalculation
    *1st value[1] = If(Type[1]=0, balance[1]*fact[1], balance[1]*fact[1]/(1-fact[1]))

    *rounded value[i] = If(1st value[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)
    *rounded value[1] = If(1st value[1]>0, rounddown(1st value[1], 1), roundup(1st value[1],2)

    *load[1] = balance[1] + rounded value[1]

    * i > 1 - ord > 1
    *1st value[i] = If(Type[i]=0, load[i-1]*fact[i], load[i-1]*fact[i]/(1-fact[i]))

    *rounded value[i] = If(1st value[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)

    *load[i+1] = load[i] + rounded value[i+1] (i >= 1)

    Local lnBalance
    Select CrsB
    Index On Padl(Id,10,'0')+Padl(ord,10,'0') Tag ALinkB
    Select crsA
    Set Relation To Padl(Id,10,'0') Into CrsB
    Scan
        lnBalance = crsA.Balance
        Select CrsB
        Scan While Id = crsA.Id
            Replace ;
                firstValue With m.lnBalance*fact / Iif(!Type, 1, 1-fact),  ;
                roundVal With Iif(firstValue > 0, ;
                roundDown(firstValue,1), ;
                roundUp(firstValue, 2))
            lnBalance = m.lnBalance + CrsB.roundVal
        Endscan
        Select crsA
        Replace Load With m.lnBalance
    Endscan
Endproc

Procedure GetDataFromExcel(tcExcelFileName, tcTableARange, tcTableBRange)
    Local lcConStr
    lcConStr = ;
        'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;'+;
        'Data Source='+Fullpath(m.tcExcelFileName)+';'+;
        'Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"'
    Local lcSQLA, lcSQLB

    TEXT to lcSQLA textmerge noshow
Select [id], [balance], [load], [state]
from [Sheet1$<< m.tcTableARange >>]
    ENDTEXT

    TEXT to m.lcSQLB textmerge noshow
select
   [Load Id] as LoadId,
   [Id], [Ord], [Fact], [Type],
   [1st value] as firstValue,
   [Rounded value] as roundVal,
   [State]
from [Sheet1$<< m.tcTableBRange >>]
    ENDTEXT

    ADOQuery(m.lcConStr, m.lcSQLA, "crsTableA")
    ADOQuery(m.lcConStr, m.lcSQLB, "crsTableB")

    Select Cast(Id As Int) As Id, Cast(Balance As Double) As Balance, ;
        Cast(Load As Double) As Load, Cast(State As c(1)) As State ;
        from crsTableA ;
        into Cursor crsA ;
        readwrite
    Select Cast(LoadId As Int) As LoadId, ;
        Cast(Id As Int) As Id, Cast(ord As Int) As ord, ;
        Cast(fact As Double) As fact, Cast(Type As logical) As Type, ;
        Cast(firstValue As Double) As firstValue, ;
        Cast(roundVal As Double) As roundVal, ;
        Cast(State As c(1)) As State From crsTableB ;
        into Cursor CrsB ;
        readwrite
    Use In (Select('crsTableA'))
    Use In (Select('crsTableB'))
Endproc

Procedure roundUp(tnValue, tnPlaces)
    If Round(m.tnValue, m.tnPlaces) = m.tnValue
        Return m.tnValue
    Else
        Return Round(m.tnValue+((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
    Endif
Endproc

Procedure roundDown(tnValue, tnPlaces)
    If Round(m.tnValue, m.tnPlaces) = m.tnValue
        Return m.tnValue
    Else
        Return Round(m.tnValue-((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
    Endif
Endproc

Procedure ADOQuery(tcConStr,tcQuery,tcCursorName)
    Local oConn As 'ADODB.Connection'
    Local oRS As ADODB.RecordSet
    oConn = Createobject('ADODB.Connection')
    oConn.Mode= 1  && adModeRead
    oConn.Open( m.tcConStr )
    oRS = oConn.Execute(m.tcQuery)
    RS2Cursor(oRS,m.tcCursorName)
    oRS.Close
    oConn.Close
Endproc


Procedure RS2Cursor(toRS, tcCursorName) && simple single cursor - not intended for complex ones
    tcCursorName = Iif(Empty(m.tcCursorName),'ADORs',m.tcCursorName)
    Local xDOM As 'MSXML.DOMDocument'
    xDOM = Createobject('MSXML.DOMDocument')
    toRS.Save(xDOM, 1)
    Xmltocursor(xDOM.XML, m.tcCursorName)
Endproc
```

EDIT: I edited the other answer for the comments beneath it. Now for your questions:

> 1. Shouldn't GetDataFromExcel("c:\myFolder\myExcel.xlsx", "B9:E12", "G9:N19") get called after the Procedure Procedure
>      GetDataFromExcel(tcExcelFileName, tcTableARange, tcTableBRange)??

No. Procedures are always placed after normal execution code in a prg file. IOW if your PRG has:

```
Do Something
* ...

Procedure SomeProcedure
* ...
endproc

Procedure Something
endproc
```

Code starts with calling Something and executes the lines after that up until it sees the first Procedure call (or FUNCTION, DEFINE CLASS). Something might be a procedure (as in the sample) or a separate prg.

> 2. Shouldn't Procedure roundUp and Procedure roundDown get called before roundDown(firstValue,1), ; roundUp(firstValue, 2))??

No, same as the above. What you say more looks like the rules of core C.

> 3. Does the left ID on this line Scan While Id = crsA.Id come from CrsB?? Also, why is there the change from crsA to CrsA? Is this a
>      typo? – user177196 5 mins ago

Yes. it comes from crsB. But in a sense, you are right I should be explicit and include the alias there as:

```
Scan while crsB.Id = crsA.Id
```

In VFP if you don't include an alias, then the one that is current is assumed.

We are scanning crsA in outer loop. Then we are switching to crsB and scanning there, after we are done switching back to crsA (actually scan command remembers the alias it is associated and does this switch when it hits endscan implicitly but I prefer to be explicit).

EDIT:

```
    Select CrsB
    Index On Padl(Id,10,'0')+Padl(ord,10,'0') Tag ALinkB
    Select crsA
    Set Relation To Padl(Id,10,'0') Into CrsB
```

On first two lines we are selecting crsB cursor and creating an index on it. Index expression contains both the Id and Old fields. VFP doesn't support multiple column names in an index key, but it supports expressions. Padding both fields with 10 zeros we are creating keys like:

Id, Ord: 2,3 as an example has a key 00000000020000000003

We could make it smaller but anyway since not knowing how much big the Id,Ord could be made it 10 in length to fit any 32 bits integer value.

Then on 3rd, 4th lines we are selecting cursor crsA and then setting relation from crsA into crsB via the expression Padl(Id,10,'0') - Id padded with 10 zeros. From crsA Id:1 has a relation key of 0000000001 then (matching all index keys that start with 0000000001 whatever the Ord part is - BTW having Ord in index too makes sure that they are ordered by Ord).

In effect, when the record pointer points to Id:1 in crsA, in crsB automatically those with Id:1 are matched (best observed with a browse - browse crsB then select crsA and browse. As you navigate in crsA, you would see the browse window for crsB would show only the rows with matching Id). Conceptually it looks like this controlling the record pointer in both cursors:

```
crsA (id)      crsB (Id, Ord)
1 ----+------- 1,1
      +------- 1,2 
      +------- 1,3 
      +------- 1,4 

2 ----+------- 2,1
      +------- 2,2 
      +------- 2,3
```

I used that because it is a powerful feature of VFP was an easier way to express what you want. The same could be achieved by using SQL Update too, however, VFP's SQL is not that much powerful and would be much more complex to write (For [1] easy but for > 1 case it gets complex - it was also not so easy in other backends too in distant past but in time, backends like postgreSQL, MS SQL server ... etc have gained much more support for such queries).

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I have some questions that I think I need your further clarification on:
1. Shouldn't `GetDataFromExcel("c:\myFolder\myExcel.xlsx", "B9:E12", "G9:N19")` get called **after** the `Procedure Procedure GetDataFromExcel(tcExcelFileName, tcTableARange, tcTableBRange)`??
2. Shouldn't `Procedure roundUp` and `Procedure roundDown` get called **before** `roundDown(firstValue,1), ;
                roundUp(firstValue, 2))`??
3. Does the left ID on this line `Scan While Id = crsA.Id` come from CrsB?? Also, why is there the change from `crsA` to `CrsA`? Is this a typo?

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I have a simple question: is this line `Select CrsB` should be `Select crsB`?

Comment: @user177196, it doesn't matter. VFP is not case sensitive in writing alias names, fieldnames, keywords ... But for readable code you are right, I also prefer crsB (you can use ALT + T, Y for code formatting).

Comment: can you try your code with this dataset (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uCWwt5ubd2_F8w2gsh3v4VDpibWz7PAz) to see if you will get the two output tables from your code, each similar to the one shown in the previous Excel worksheet I uploaded for you? Also, is `Procedure RS2Cursor(toRS, tcCursorName)` intended to generate the **2** output tables? Why do we need this procedure though: `Procedure ADOQuery(tcConStr,tcQuery,tcCursorName)`?

Comment: Two more questions please: 1) where does the `m` come from in  `m.lnBalance`? 2) Don't we need to define  `crsTableA`? Or you meant we can use the `CREATE Table tableA` in your previous code to make `crsTableA` valid?

Comment: Also, I saw that `B9:E12` does not match the range of tableA or tableB in the Excel spreadsheet I uploaded for you before. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I have another question: can you please clarify on what these lines do: `Select CrsB
    Index On Padl(Id,10,'0')+Padl(ord,10,'0') Tag ALinkB
    Select crsA
    Set Relation To Padl(Id,10,'0') Into CrsB.`

Comment: @user177196, sorry I missed you had more questions than I noticed. I will reply the ones I missed later tonight I hope.

Comment: no need to sorry Sir, since you helped me quite a lot. I found out what does `m.` mean. Can you please help add the comments above set of lines of code above indicating what they do (eg, what does `TEXT TEXT to lcSQLA textmerge noshow` do)? Such comments will definitely be super helpful to me.

Comment: By the way, why did you choose 10 zeros (rather than say, 1 zero) to add in front of `id` and `ord` (aka, for id, ord: 2,3, is there a problem if we go with `0203`?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180696/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-user177196).

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a long question, containing multiple questions within. I will try to reply in pieces (editing my answer in between), since it would be a long answer (might even be good to divide into multiple answers).

First, your create table syntax was close but incorrect. VFP (it is not VFB but V FP by the way), does not support spaces in field names (unless it is a long fieldname). Using field names with spaces would just be asking for trouble. So prefer not using them. It would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE tableA; 
(     id    int,    ;
      balance   double, ;
      load   C(240), ;
      state  C(240))

CREATE TABLE tableB; 
(     Load id   int, ;
      id        int, ;
      ord       int, ;
      fact      double,  ;
      type      int  ;
      firstValue  C(240),;
      roundedVal  C(240), ;
      state     C(240))
```

Note that after final field you don't have comma and ; in VFP means continue the command on next line (so removed in last field definition lines). I also changed the 2 field names to be compatible with a free table's field naming (max 10 in length and must start with a letter, no spaces). Easier to use the tables this way.or cursors provided you do it in one shot and do not try to change the structure later.

If you want to use longfieldnames then you can do that just as you do with free tables but the table needs to be part of a database. It would also work for cursors provided you do that in one shot and do not attempt to alter the structure afterwards.

While I added code there to create TableA, TableB, you are saying those tables' data would come from Excel. You didn't really give detailed information about the Excel part of it (how data is represented-is that as a data ranges?). There is a great probability that you create these two tables simply by selecting the data from Excel using ODBC/OLEDB directly.

For getting data from Excel I posted some detailed information on [Foxite, you can check the post in this link](https://www.foxite.com/archives/vista-excel-compatibility-w-worksheets-0000153776.htm). I am not giving any sample code here as I don't yet know the Excel part really.

Assuming we got the data from Excel let's check other parts (BTW in table B id is called a Foreign Key, not primary. It links the rows in TableB top TableA).

```
1st value[i] = If(Type[i]=0, balance[i]*fact[i], balance[i]*fact[i]/(1-fact[i]))
```

We can use either REPLACE command (xBase command) or SQL Update command to accomplish this. Let's do not think about the differences here (not worth really) and choose SQL Update to do job (the syntax would be reusable in other databases too - say MS SQL server, postgreSQL, mySQL ...).

```
Update tableB ;
  set firstValue = iif( type = 0, ;
          tableA.balance * fact, ;
          tableA.balance * fact/(1-fact)) ;
from tableA ;
where tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

Or slightly simplified:

```
Update tableB ;
  set firstValue = tableA.balance * fact / ;
          iif( type = 0, 1, (1-fact)) ;
from tableA ;
where tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

Note that VFP would execute this expression per row so we don't need the [i] (array identifier) that you have in your pseudocode.

Next one:

```
rounded value[i] = If(Type[i]>0, rounddown(1st value[i], 1), roundup(1st value[i],2)
```

Would be translated in the same manner:

```
Update tableB ;
  set roundVal = iif(type > 0, ;
        rounddown(firstValue,1), ;
        roundup(firstValue,2)) ;
from tableA ;
where tableA.Id = tableB.Id
```

However, VFP doesn't have roundup and rounddown functions, I only wrote these as a conceptual translation. What you can do is to create two custom functions that does RoundUp and RoundDown. There are multiple ways to write these functions and IMHO the easiest would be to write them as 2 separate .prg files where those prg files are in your search path when you execute the above SQL command:

**RoundUp.prg**

```
Lparameters tnValue, tnPlaces
If Round(m.tnValue, m.tnPlaces) = m.tnValue
    Return m.tnValue
Else
    Return Round(m.tnValue+((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
Endif
```

**RoundDown.prg**

```
Lparameters tnValue, tnPlaces
If Round(m.tnValue, m.tnPlaces) = m.tnValue
    Return m.tnValue
Else
    Return Round(m.tnValue-((10^-(m.tnPlaces+1))*5), m.tnPlaces)
Endif
```

The functions in the link you provided doesn't seem right to me for the job (but was not easy to understand and test so didn't spend time on checking thoroughly).

I am not sure if one sheet containing both tables is good. I don't remember off the top of my head, if Tables collection was a member of the WorkSheet or WorkBook. If WorkSheet then that would do. I can check and write sample code for that later (possibly tomorrow).

You could use datatype LOGICAL (l) for Type. In MS SQL server and other backends it correspond to bit (1 or 0). Internally stored as boolean but in expressions used as .T./.F. (true\false symbolic representation in VFP. On code you could simply use it as:

```
iif( type, ...
```

same as saying iif(type = .T., ...) - as in Type > 0. And:

```
iif( !type, ...
```

same as saying iif( type = .F., ...) or iif( type NOT equal to .T., ... - as in Type = 0.

I didn't use inner join in this case, because it is sufficient to use a from TableA where here (same in other backends, although general tendency is to write that using join).

EDIT: Added the code as another answer.

As per your questions:
Inner join is not needed to be explicitly defined, there is an implicit join there. Instead of writing an SQL update, I preferred to utilize VFP's xBase capabilities and used scan...endscan instead (could do with SQL but would be more complex).

Yes it means putting those 2 RoundUp.prg and RoundDown.prg files into the same directory path of our main file code above BUT only if main file code is in current directory or in search path. To make it more clear, consider:

c:\SomeFolder\RoundUp.prg
c:\SomeFolder\RoundDown.prg
c:\ANOTHERFolder\Main.prg

and you are in:
c:\YetAnotherFolder

If you call main.prg like this:

```
do ('c:\ANOTHERFolder\Main.prg')
```

It needs to find RoundUp, RoundDown and it can if c:\Somefolder is included in SET('PATH') - ie:

```
Set path to c:\SomeFolder;c:\VFPHomeFolderMaybe
```

Or if you don't want to think of pathing you could include those RoundUp\Down code as procedure in the code (as I did in the code in the other answer - note that in VFP there is no difference between a PROCEDURE and a FUNCTION. You are free to choose either one. Some developers prefer to use FUNCTION for those that return a value - but in fact any PROCEDURE\FUNCTION returns a value so let's say those that are used for a return value.)

> I don't think logical type mean "1" or "0" automatically, correct? If
>   that's the case, I would have to leave it as int type, because the
>   input is always defined as 1 or 0 for type column.

Well, that is hard to answer formally. In VFP boolean data 
type is defined by literals .F. and .T. You can cast(aBoolean to int) and you get 0 and 1 respectively. Or you can cast(1 as logical) to get .T. IOW 1\0 and .T..F. are interchangeable in a sense. It all depends where you want to use it. If data is coming from external source, it would come in as 1\0. Just by casting or getting it into column of datatype logical (implicit cast) it is treated as .T..F. Or you are sending data from a logical to an external source (say an XML, MS SQL server, postgreSql, other OLEDB\ODBC datasource) then .T..F. is casted as 1\0.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, and for your great teaching on field names. How do we specify a *long fieldname* with the code though?

Comment: @user177196, please continue to add your questions here as I edit the answer so I can add the answers within the answer. I will detail it now.

Comment: Fortunately, *one* Excel spreadsheet containing two tables A and B with table A = (B9:B1000, E9:E1000) (B9-E9 are headers), and table B  = (G9:G1000, N9:N1000) shares the exact same data fields and data format as what was created in tableA and tableB above. So my question is if we can write a code to LOAD the data onto the tables created by our code.

Comment: On the other hand, I just realized I made a serious mistake in detailing the formula to compute entries in the column `1st value` of the `calculation table.` The `balance[i]` should be replaced by `load[i-1]`. My sincere apology.

Comment: the `roundup` and `roundown` function in the 2nd post here are good enough? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27fd7cd8-1c90-47fb-b5e1-781d893b3095/round-up-and-round-down-and-round-function?forum=visualfoxprogeneral

Comment: do you know how can we define a column that takes only two values (0 or 1)? The `type` column in tableA should have binary data type.

Comment: Also, I saw that you do not use Inner Join. Is the condition tableA.Id = tableB.Id sufficient?? I meant, for each entry in column `Id` of tableB, we need to compute the corresponding entries in `1st value[i]`, `rounded value[i]` and `load[i]` in the `calculation table.` But then for the updated tableA, we only choose the last entry in `load` for each Id (because if you look at tableB, when `Id==1`, we are supposed to have 4 values of load[1], ..., load[4]. But only `load[4]` is chosen for `Id==1` in tableA.

Comment: I made another mistake in the formula for `rounded value[i].` I fixed it though. My apology to you Sir. But can you help fix your update for `table B` with the new formulas? What I am concerned is how to write `for` loop inside, as for each `id`, we have a recursion formula to compute `firstvalue`.

Comment: @user177196, I am afraid I didn't understand "1st value of the calculation table. The balance[i] should be replaced by load[i-1]". Load is null at that point.

Comment: why load is null at that point though? The step for computations is:
- Compute `load[1] = balance[1] + rounded value[1].` 

- For id= 1, compute: `1st value[next row] = load[previous row]*(fact assigned to each id).` Then use the rule to roundup or roundown `1st value[next row]` to obtain `rounded value[next row].`

- Compute `load[next row] = 1st value[next row] + rounded value[next row]` for next row = 2,3,4.

These only apply to a **fixed** id. **New** id means starting over this process!!

Comment: Look like we have to use things like: 
"For n = min(tableA.id) to max(tableA.id) 
      DO While tableB.id == n
          [fill in the recursion formula here]
from tableA, tableB;
ENDDO
"

Comment: @user177196,  after your edits it looks more confusing. load calculation depends on roundedValue which depend on firstValue. firstValue uses load. If we start with firstValue, then load is null. Can you provide a full sample with say one given Id. (I can check tomorrow in any case)

Comment: Let me edit again. `firstValue[1]` will be computed with `balance[id=1]`, and the formula above applies for `i>=2` until the last row that has `id==1` in tableB. Then everything repeats. I am making an Excel spreadsheet to make things clearer for you.

Comment: here is the link to the Excel spreadsheet: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16RVL6lDef8joQqynsw1UA0l9Kzn22_9q. 

I am sure that you will see all the recursions required in the code now. There are two things that I find quite difficult: 1). For each fixed `id`, how do we write a code to pick an element in `load` column that corresponds to the maximum element in `ord` column, where both columns belong to `calculation table`. 2) Must Inner Join be used, because we have to match each elements in `id` column of `A` with *every* same element in the same column of `B`?

Comment: Btw, does this sentence "write them as 2 separate .prg files where those prg files are in your search path when you execute the above SQL command" mean "putting those 2 RoundUp.prg and RoundDown.prg files" into the same directory path of our main file code above? Don't we need to call these 2 files out in the main file in order to execute the `rounddown`, `roundup` in the code??

Comment: Btw, I don't think logical type mean "1" or "0" automatically, correct? If that's the case, I would have to leave it as `int` type, because the input is always defined as `1` or `0` for `type` column.

Comment: so if I define `type l;` and the data loaded into this column `type` coming from an external sources (eg. Excel spreadsheet) contains numbers not 0 or 1, would there be error message, or would those numbers still be loaded as they are into this column?

Comment: @user177196, they would be loaded as .T.\.F. (1\0).

Comment: Even when the input data is not 0 or 1 for that column `type`?? That is not what we want, we want error message for those mis-labeling data;p

Comment: @user177196, no you got me wrong (rereading looks like I got you wrong). I meant 1\0 would be converted to .T.\.F. Never tried with values other than that, so I should try first.